# How do I fix a twisted shower head?

Tags: shower, faucet

I have one of those shower heads that has a twisty bendy cord that allows you to wash specific areas my easily. Also makes washing pets easier in the tub as well.

The last week or so the shower head has been wanting to twist itself to the far stage right. Towards the bathroom/shower curtain!

It also will not stay "up" all the way.

Being a tall man this renders it unusable and I've no idea how to fix it. I've tried twisting it the opposite direction as many times and it'll twist (about 2 and a half) and it twists "back" into the normal position. But as soon as I run water through it, it goes back to it far right twisted position and points further down.

Is it worn out or is there something I can do to fix it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try letting the shower head hang for a few days while it's not in use. This might help "unwind" the plastic. You could even run hot water through it once in a while, while it's hanging, to help the re-straightening process. Next trick would be to remove it and place it in hot water then let it cool while hanging.

Answer (score 0):

If you've had the shower head for any longer than a year or two, it may make sense to just replace it.

Between all the inevitable mineral deposits inside its piping that can never be truly cleaned out, and all the hot water, effort and time you'll spend trying to straighten it out, might as well get a new one that works the way it's been designed to.

Answer (score 0):

I have been bothered by twisted shower heads my whole life, and only recently I realized there is often a very easy solution for the problem. Just let the shower head do a full turn in the direction that it wants to twist and put it back on the holder. It should be fine now. If it still twists in the same direction as before, you can do another full turn.